# What's wrong with the containers

Tags: html, css

changing overflow property of the second container to "hidden" somehow breaks the surrounding container:

```css
.title {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  
  /* debug */
  background-color: blue;
}

.first {
  /* debug */
  background-color: green;
}

.second {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  
  /* debug */
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="title">
    <span class="first">Start</span>
    <span class="second"> end</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is not the `overflow`, it's `display: inline-block;`:

```css
.title {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  /* debug */
  background-color: blue;
}

.first {
  /* debug */
  background-color: green;
}

.second {
  overflow: hidden;

  /* debug */
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="title">
    <span class="first">Start</span>
    <span class="second"> end</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Edit:

If it must be `display: inline-block;`, add `vertical-align: text-bottom;`:

```css
.title {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  /* debug */
  background-color: blue;
}

.first {
  /* debug */
  background-color: green;
}

.second {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  /* debug */
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="title">
    <span class="first">Start</span>
    <span class="second"> end</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need it to be inline-block

Comment: Check updated answer.